# install usb-scanner brother MFC-215C ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb, scanner

I want to install the above device, but no success. lsusb says:

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f9:0193 Brother Industries, Ltd MFC-215C.
```

`scanimage -L` doesn't find the device, `sudo sane-find-scanner` says:

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04ca [Broadcom Corp], product=0x2009 [BCM43142A0]) at libusb:003:002.
```

What's going wrong?

dmesg gives: scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Brother  MFC-215C         1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2

Comment: you need to install a driver: http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/download_scn.html#brscan2

Comment: driver is already installed

Comment: dmesg gives: scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Brother  MFC-215C         1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2    May be a problem!?